# Analysis $\epsilon-N$ notation, switching between rigorous proof and intuition.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, epsilon-delta, cauchy-sequences

I once saw a proof for convergence for a specific problem involving fixed point iteration 
showing $|a_n-L| \leq (1/2)^n \rightarrow 0 $  and so $a_n\rightarrow L$

I initially did not understand why they were deciding to abandon $\epsilon-N$ notation now and that it was some sort of handwavy, sketchy explanation since this was in an Applied Mathematics book and not a rigorous Analysis book
but realised that it was perfectly legitimate since $|a_n - L| $ is equivalent to $||a_n - L|-0|$- add in the $\epsilon-N$ and that becomes an if and only if.

So in words that's if $a_n$ tends to $L$ then the difference between them gets closer and closer to $0$.

Similarly for showing a sequence is Cauchy: we want all $m,n$ past a certain point to be close enough to each other. So like before I plan to show that $|a_m-a_n| \rightarrow 0$ but my problem here I am dealing with two points and there's infinitely many of them.

Does the following work?

WLOG let $m>n$ ($m=n$ being trivial).

Then $m=n+k$ for some $k>0$

we now want $|a_{n+k}-a_n| < \epsilon$ (assume the stuff about n>N is all there- just boring to keep writing out)

But by the reasoning above this is the same as $|a_{n+k}-a_n| \rightarrow 0$

and by the triangle inequality we know that $|a_{n+k}-a_n|\leq|a_{n+k}-a_{n+k-1}|+|a_{n+k-1}-a_{n+k-2}|+...+|a_{n+1}-a_{n}|$

Now in my specific problem I have managed to find a bound $\forall n$

That is:

$\forall n$ 
$|a_{n+1}-a_n|\leq  c(1/2)^n$ where $c$ is a constant from the problem. So by Alegbra of Limits the whole sum on RHS tends to $0 $and so the left hand side tends to $0$ by sandwiching and so we're done $a_n$ is a Cauchy Sequence.

If this is flawed please could you point out where.

Comment: Well, it's slightly "flawed" in not being that well written - we don't hear about the _hypotheses_ in the result you're trying to prove until the end of the proof, etc. But it's a valid proof of the following, which I gather is what you wanted to show: If $|a_{n+1}-a_n|\le c2^{-n}$ then $(a_n)$ is Cauchy. (The same holds assuming just $\sum_n|a_{n+1}-a_n|<\infty$.)

Comment: I don't understand that last line of yours- why would it be cauchy just because that sum is less than infinity- say the sum was $3$- pick $\epsilon=0.1$ how could you guanrantee you can find an $N$ now?

Comment: If $c_n\ge0$ and  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n<\infty$ then for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ so $\sum_{n=N}^\infty c_n<\epsilon$. In calculus they refer to this fact by saying "the tail of a convergent series tends to $0$".

Comment: Also say my bound did not exist or at least I didnt know about it and I knew nothing about $|a_{n+1} - a_n|$ . Would the idea of forgetting about $m$ and using $n+k$ and $n$ in general be a good idea of showing sequences were Cauchy.

Comment: Whether you talk about $a_m-a_n$ or $a_{n+k}-a_n$ really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

> If this is flawed please could you point out where.

The premise of the question is flawed. The original observation, bounding the error by $(1/2)^n$, is a demonstration of convergence that doesn't need any more $\epsilon$ work to "justify" further.  The point of the epsilon notation is to give a rigorous language to discuss asymptotics but here you already have the asymptotic bound in a rather specific form, so no epsilon assistance is required.

With that said, given a strong bound like $(1/2)^n$ it is possible to force it into whatever form a class or textbook on real analysis canonizes as the Only Allowed Protocol for a convergence argument.   But if it isn't already fully clear from the bound that convergence has occurred, the class has failed in one of its basic purposes.